# Why does turning array into Tensor add dimensionality?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, lstm

When I turn my ndarray into a Ragged Tensor, dimensions are added for no reason, resulting into errors: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_8 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, None, None, None]`

Upon running this code, observe what happens:

```
print(XTrain.shape)
x_train = tf.ragged.constant(XTrain)
print(x_train.shape)

print(XTrain[1].shape)
print(x_train[1].shape)
```

(10000,)
(10000, None, None, None)
(821, 1, 26)
(821, None, None)

As you can see, not only is the ragged tensor losing the dimensionality that was added on purpose np.ndarray: (821,1,26) --> tf.ragged.constant --> (821, None, None)

How can I make sure that it doesn't add the random three nones which trigger the ValueError above?

Comment: well, RaggedTensor is not expected to have fixed dimensions

Comment: I submitted [issue #40159](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40159) about this precise problem.

Comment: Is there any way it can be fixed? I have no idea why the shape it's detecting is [None, None, None, None]... very weird...

Answer (score 0):

In the input layer, one must specify `ragged=True`, so that this dimensionality is ignored.